# How to change the encoding of all illegitimate characters in Visual Studio Code at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code, character-encoding

I'm using Visual Studio Code for my projects. Occasionally, I copy texts from computer programs like MS Word that include punctuations like " and ' in different encodings. These must be changed or the web pages will be full of messy characters.

I have installed the Gremlins extension to help me detect these unusual characters in HTML files. I'm currently changing the detected characters mannually, and this is a lot of pain.

Is there a solution for switching the character encoding of all these unusual characters at once?

Comment: _"All_ characters are special." -- tchrist

Comment: `iconv` with `ascii//translit` as the target encoding on the text would do it, outside of VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: Just explicitly define encoding in HTML files with:

`<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`